# LineageOS / bardockpro / recent LineageOS installation package do not work

Tags: rom-flashing, lineageos, bootloader-lock, builds

I have been happily using and occasionally upgrading a [bardockpro device](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/bardockpro) for many months.

However, in summer 2019 the device stopped booting into upgrades that were released after July. The most recent build that works, insofar as I know, is the 20190710 nightly build.

Since then occasionally I tried newer builds - never successfully. I habve also flashed stock rom. and then retried recent lineageos builds. No success.

The problem, in my reading of an [issue](https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/issues/959)  is that the device is not critically unlocked. Therefore not all parts can effectively can be flashed.

so, one question was: how to
get

```
Device critical unlocked: false
```

to

```
Device critical unlocked: true
```

?

However, my reading of the issue was misleading - and this was not the question. The question was way less specific: how to get the device working with the updated builds?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3704406

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution emerged in a conversation in the [German Android-Hilfe](https://www.android-hilfe.de/forum/root-custom-roms-modding-fuer-bq-aquaris-x-x-pro.3058/lineageos-pakete-seit-juli-funktionieren-nicht-auf-bardockpro.935672.html). The solution was to

- flash an older Stock ROM version.
- let the Stock ROM update itself, and in that process, seemingly, get all the partitions "right".

Afterwards I was able to install recent Lineage OS builds following the standard installation instructions.